# Confused on Power BI embedding

Tags: azure-activedirectory, microsoft-powerbi

I am trying to embed a report I made onto my company's internal website. I have tried for days to get an AAD Token, but am very confused about the process as well if it's what I even need.

I have generated an embed token easily enough using Powershell ISE. The problem is that the token deactivates after an hour and I have to refresh it manually. I also tried using a Visual Studio program to generate what I thought was an Azure Active Directory (AAD) token, but I got the same type of token that I did with Powershell.

Then I learned about a subscription service called Power BI Embed that looks like it does what I want, but it has an hourly cost associated with it.

I just want to confirm if an AAD token is what I want, auto refresh, unlimited hits, or if the Power BI Embed service is what I'd need.

Comment: Does the audience have Power BI Pro licenses or do you have Power BI Premium?

Comment: Lets assume that the audience does not have Power BI Pro licenses, and I only have Power BI Pro. 

I assume this would mean that Embed is the best option?

Comment: No, the best option would be to buy Power BI Pro licenses for the audience, unless the audience is 500+